# calling a specific fragment results in having to change the 1st parameter

Tags: android

This worked previously but now and I suspect, after updates, it's no longer working:

```
 private void beginTransction(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();


//TODO: call the players fragment
                    beginTransction(new PlayersFragment());
```

would result in error: Change first parameter of method "beginTransction" from "Fragment" to "PlayersFragment"

This defeats the purpose of calling other fragments.

Comment: Lookes like a mixup of native fragemnts and support fragments. Check your import statements.

Answer (score 0):

That was it!!!
I had mixed-up the imports.
import android.app.Fragment used in the fragments and import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment used in the mainactivity
Thanks